Using Basic Authentication and JWT Token Authentication both in a .Net Core Web API Application
I have a .Net Core web API application currently using JWT Token Authentication approach. there is a requirement to provide some APIs to a exnternal integration with Basic Authentication approach. How can I acheive both options in a single .Net Core Web API solution?
I tried to add Basic authentication and it overided the existing the Token authentication.

Please provide an example code.

Auth in Asp Net Core consists of Authentication schemes and Authorization policies.
You need to register a few authentication schemes:
.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultScheme = "samlScheme"
 })
.AddWebSaml(
   "samlScheme",
   options =>
   {...}
)
.AddJwtBearer(
   "jwtScheme",
   options =>
   {...}
)
.AddCustomeScheme(
   "scheme3",
   options =>
   {...}
);

Now, only the SAML scheme will be used when you have [Authorize] attribute, because we specified it as the default scheme which will be used by default policy.
Fortunately, we can specify a policy like [Authorize("NotDefaultPolicyName")]
And we need to register this policy:
.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("NotDefaultPolicyName", policy =>
    {
      policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("jwtScheme");
      policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
      ...
    });
});

Now controllers/actions marked with default [Authorize] will enforce the "samlScheme"
And marked with [Authorize("NotDefaultPolicyName")] will enforce the "jwtScheme".
I have a good article Demystifying Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Core: Under the Hood if you want to get more insights into Auth in Asp

Here's how you can implement both JWT Token Authentication and Basic Authentication in a single .NET Core Web API application. This approach allows you to use both authentication schemes without one overriding the other.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
    });

    services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

    services.AddControllers();
}


You need to implement a handler for Basic Authentication:
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");

        var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        if (authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
        {
            var encodedCredentials = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCredentials);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(':', 2);
            var username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];

            // Validate user credentials
            if (IsValidUser(username, password)) // Implement your validation logic
            {
                var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
                return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
            }
        }
        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authentication");
    }

    private bool IsValidUser(string username, string password)
    {
        // Implement your user validation logic here
        return true; // Placeholder for actual validation
    }
}



In the Configure method, ensure that authentication is enabled:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication(); // Enable authentication
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}



Specify which authentication method to use on your API endpoints:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("api/jwt-secured")]
public IActionResult JwtSecuredEndpoint()
{
    return Ok("JWT authenticated");
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]
[HttpGet("api/basic-secured")]
public IActionResult BasicSecuredEndpoint()
{
    return Ok("Basic authenticated");
}



